# Having problems with FB Like Button and G+1 button code on same page

Tags: html, facebook, header, google-plus, facebook-like

I can imagine the sighs - but have searched here and google and FB and can't find the answer.

Facebook requires the  tag to show:

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

Google+ requires the  tag to show (for example):

```
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness">
```

I've combined the 2 in this way:

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness">
```

When the G+1 button is clicked the Google Box pops up and comments can be added, etc to the +1 post appearing in the +1ers stream. However when the FB Like button is clicked the Facebook box no longer pops up to allow comments to be added to the like - the like is recorded though. Is there a problem with either the code or the way implemented?

=================================================================

Update: see this page http://www.photogenix.biz/prints/2011/still-life-watches1.php I have discovered that the code for the FB Like button has changed. I have moved the G+ code to the body tag to take it out of the equation and updated the `<html>` tag and code at the foot of the page to the XFBML version as described https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ The same page with '1' removed from the end shows my original code (old FBML version) - both versions appear to operate the same way. The bizarre thing is that the Send button generates the pop up box but the like button doesn't. Do you think this might be a Facebook known issue? The G+ code / pop-up works fine too so there's nothing hidden as far as I can see. Seems bizarre behaviour.

Comment: Can you reliably reproduce previous behaviour by reverting the tag to the FB-only version?

Comment: @richsage yes, it hasn't worked for a while but I did test removing the Google code and the FB Like button produced a pop up box for user comment when clicked.

Comment: @richsage actually Rich I've just tested again removing the G+ code from html tag and it no longer produces the FB pop up box to add comment when like is pressed. Maybe an issue with the FB part of the code I guess although I did include the G+ code in the body tag as suggested in the answer below and testing that the G+ code seems to work when placed there.

Comment: @richsageI may be getting confused but I was sure when you click the FB Like button there should be a pop up to add comment. Maybe I'm wrong. Can't reproduce the pop up now at all.

Answer (score 0):

`itemscope` goes in the `<body>` element. https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/+1button/#plus-snippet

Comment: Oh thanks @abraham for the link. If you go to the configuration tool it says something different - apologies if the link doesn't display correctly [link]http://www.google.com/webmasters/+1/button/

Comment: Hmmm... It looks like `itemscope` and `itemtype` can be in either `<html>` or `<body>` if the entire page is relevant, otherwise specific sections of the page. http://schema.org/docs/gs.html#microdata_itemscope_itemtype